# Allow range function to evaluate non numerical expression

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, while-loop

I am using a makearange function to input a start, stop, and increment range for an array i.e.

```
User = raw_input('Enter start,[stop],[increment]: ').split(',')
makearange = lambda a: numpy.arange(int(a[0]),int(a[1]),int(a[2]))
x = makearange(User)
```

However I am also using these numbers to run a program to create arrays of the squares and cubes of the inputted numbers. I am running this program on an infinite while loop, which only stops when the user hits the return key. So I have tried

```
if User == "":
    Break
```

Which would work except this results in an error because the makearange function only evaluates integers and not the user input of the return key. How can I get it to understand this type of input?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Instead of immediately trying to split `User` on commas, test if it is the empty string first:

```
import numpy as np
import sys

user_input = raw_input('Enter [start,] stop[, increment]: ')
if user_input = '':
    sys.exit()
else:
    x=np.arange(*map(int,user_input.split(',')))
```

PS. `Enter start,[stop],[increment]` suggests that `stop` and `increment` are optional. Does that mean if only one argument is given, you want the range to start from the given number and increase infinitely? That's won't work with `numpy.arange`. Perhaps you meant the `start` to be optional, and the `stop` to be required. That would fit perfectly with the way `numpy.arange` already works.

Comment: This type of condition `if user_input != '':` does not really cover the possibility of non-empty non-integerable input.

Comment: Right, but since that was not central to the question asked, I decided not to go into that.

Comment: Sorry yes, I was having separate problems with this, I have been asked to make stop and increment optional, by setting default values for both although I haven't yet worked out how to do this as I am completely new to programming.

Answer (score 0):

```
makearange = lambda a: numpy.arange(int(a[0]),int(a[1]),int(a[2])) if len(a) == 3 else None
```

of course you can come up with a better validation than the length of the array